# Relation between nullspace and row-equivalence of matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n \mathbb{Z}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Two matrices $D$ and $E$ over a field have the same nullspace if only if they are row-equivalent. Is the same true if those matrices are over the ring of integers ($\mathbb{Z}$) or integers mod a fixed positive integer ($\mathbb{Z}/(n \mathbb{Z})$)?

Comment: The elementary row operation of multiplication by a constant must be by a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ otherwise the operation won't be invertible. I have no idea if defining row equivalence with this constraint to row operations would still be equivalent to defining row equivalence as just having the same row-space.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ usually refers to $p$-adic numbers. Please be explicit on your notation.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}$, having the same kernel is weaker. For instance, take one integer matrix, and multiply it by any number that is not $0$ or $1$. The kernel remains the same, but the two matrices are no longer row equivalent.

Comment: Row operations over $\mathbb Z$ give you the Hermite normal form.

Comment: For completeness, the analog of the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) over the integers is the [Howell normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howell_normal_form) over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.